# Compression Ratio of two Mat images?

Tags: c++, opencv

I was wondering how you would go about calculating the compression ratio of two mat images and outputting it as a float/int?

I tried just doing

```
  (inputImg.getSize()/ouputImg.getSize()) * 100
```

but it doesn't work.

Any advice would be much appreciated

Comment: Mat does not know about compression, the size won't ever change ;)  if you *save* it, though, the number of bytes on disk will differ

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no compression while manipulating the Mat structure. Store it in a file using OpenCV routines and compare the size of the file and the size of the corresponding Mat object.
The ratio should depend on the file format you choose though.